# Overwrite global scss class from module scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, css-modules

I have an issue trying to modify a style of my global.scss from my component scss module.

On my global.scss I have the following class

```
.container_page {
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

then I would like to do the following on my component scss

```
.container_page {
  min-width: 1200px !important;
}
```

I have tried access the global class like this but I got an error of pure selector:

```
:global .container_page {  min-width: 1200px !important; }
```

And also using a local class before, but it does not work

```
.banner_home :global .container_page {  min-width: 1200px !important; }
```

Can you guys help to find out how to achieve my goal?